# Cannot assign a value of type nsnumber to a value type string

Tags: xcode, swift, nsnumberformatter

I'm using number formatter to change a value number from a JSON to a number with commas (e.g. `500000` to `500,000`). I think I have it down but I'm getting an error saying:

> cannot assign a value of type nsnumber to a value type string

```
if let supply = json["supply"] as? NSNumber{
    var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(supply)!
    totalXRP.text = supply

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the result of `numberFormatter.stringFromNumber` to your text field:

```
if let supply = json["supply"] as? NSNumber{
    var numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    if let result = numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(supply) {
        totalXRP.text = result
    }
}
```

Comment: "still didn't work" is not useful. What is the error message? Where does it appear? Etc. Give details and context if you want help.

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the label, it's blank

Comment: Then replace `totalXRP.text = result` by `println(result)`: what does it print? If the string is empty or nil, then you know why it doesn't work. If it's not nil, then it means you have a different problem, probably something with the label itself. Also, debug by printing the content of `json["supply"]`, maybe the problem is here.

Comment: Ok so it's empty since nothing is being printed from println(result)

Comment: It probably means that `supply` isn't a valid number.